# PhoneGap app fit all sizes

Tags: javascript, android, html, phonegap

So, I have just started using PhoneGap and PhoneGap Build to make and build my apps but I have one problem, how do I make my app fit all screen sizes like tablets and phones, is there something I have to do in the XML file or is there something else that PhoneGap requires me to do?

Comment: Are you having trouble after testing on different devices or is this more of a general question? PhoneGap natively supports reponsive design and should not cause issues on different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap is natively responsive, so you do not need to do anything to make it work on different sized screens. That being said, you should follow the guidelines of [responsive web desing](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp) to make sure your content looks good on all devices.